# C++ Remove function not working

Tags: c++, filestream

Trying to edit some info in a text file. I change what I need, leave what I don't, and the put it in a temporary text file. Once the program is done, I want to delete the old text file and rename the temporary one the name of the old one.

Remove does not seem to be working in this case...

```
else if (input == 2){
        cout<<"Work?"<<endl;
        string checkUser = username; //set checkUser var equal to username var
        string checkPass = password;
        ofstream outfile("pleasework.txt");
        ifstream infile("userinfo.txt"); //CREATING IFSTREAM
        string u, p, b;
        cout<<checkUser;
        while(infile>>u>>p>>b)
            {
           //cout<<"PLeae"<<endl;
           cout<<u<<' '<<p<<' '<<b<<endl;
            if(checkUser == u){
            cout<<"Current Balance: "<<balance<<endl;
            cout<<"Enter new balance: ";
            int newBalance;
            cin>>newBalance;
            outfile<<checkUser<<' '<<checkPass<<' '<<newBalance<<endl;
            //outfile<<username<<' '<<password<<' '<<newBalance<<endl;
            }else
            {
            outfile<<u<<' '<<p<<' '<<b<<endl;
            }//end else
        }//end while
            infile.close();
            cout<<"Infile closed"<<endl;
            outfile.close();
            cout<<"Outfile closed"<<endl;
            remove("userinfo.txt");
            cout<<"Were past remove!"<<endl;
            int result;
            char oldname[] = "pleasework.txt";
            char newname[] = "userinfo.txt";
            rename(oldname, newname);
            //result = rename (oldname, newname);
            result = (remove("userinfo.txt"));
            if(result == 0)
                puts("file was renamed");
            else
                perror("Error");
            return 0;

    }
```

I keep getting "Error: File Exists!"
Have I missed closing the file somewhere?

Comment: You check the result of `rename` but not `remove`. I would check that. Also, `if(result = 0)` -> `if(result == 0)`

Comment: @cparks10: How are we supposed to know whether you closed that file or not? Did even open it? It is not clear from the code snippet you posted.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp  Ok, I changed that and now I am getting "Error: Permission Denied!"

Comment: @AnT I added more of my code to show you where I use if ifstream and osfstream functions.

Comment: May be noted that this is from a much larger program. I created a smaller version of this and it works just fine. That is what is leading me to believe that I have missed closing a file somewhere else in the large program, but can't seem to find the place where that could be. Hopefully it is somewhere in the posted code above.

Comment: Why do you have `remove("userinfo.txt")` twice? I believe the second one should be `remove("pleasework.txt")`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Nevermind, I solved the problem thanks to your troubleshooting! I appreciate it!